# odoo 11: how do i prevent a delivery order is created upon sales confirmation

Tags: automation, odoo, odoo-11

If i confirm a sales order odoo automatically creates a corresponding delivery order. However, this process is not quite right forour purpose where we want to have a delivery order being created ONLY after payment is received.

I somehow recall there was a way to change those workflows in previous versions, but do not find anything regarding this topic in odoo 11. Anyone got an idea on how to teach odoo that creating a delivery order must be manually triggered or after payment is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it by overriding existing function : "_create_delivery_line"  as there is no more workflow in the latest versions of odoo ,

Comment: so does that mean that whenever i need to adapt a workflow slightly, this becomes a coding exercise rather than configuration? I do not understand entirely why the wokflow engine had been removed, is there any rational thought behind that?

Comment: The workflows are not used in Odoo anymore from version 11 on. They were considered harder to migrate and to deal with because of the lack of flexibility.So instead of workflow you need to use button calling python methods.